# Turtle-RDF ontology (OWL) - is base re-use possible?

Tags: syntax, owl, turtle-rdf

Instead of having to copy the full IRI when defining the ontology in Turtle,
is there a way to re-use the `@base`, `:` or `my-base:` instead?

> NOTE: `@base` provides a prefix for relative IRIs using `<...>`.
>         So in the example below,
>         `<Entity>` expands to `<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#Entity>`.

Could I use any of the first three lines instead of the 4th line from below (`<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity>`)?

```
@base          <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
@prefix :      <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
@prefix ent:   <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity>
  a owl:Ontology .
```

Comment: `<>
  a owl:Ontology .` should work, but `: a owl:Ontology . ` would not

Answer (score 3):

> NOTE: `@base` provides a prefix for relative IRIs using `<...>`. So in the example below, `<Entity>` expands to `<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#Entity>`.

Where did you get this idea from? This is not the case. `@base` is not prefixing whatever is in between the `<` and `>`. `@base` defines the base IRI over which relative IRIs are resolved. Resolving relative IRIs is more complicated than concatenating two strings.

First, a base IRI is necessarily stripped off of its trailing `#` and any fragment identifier. So, if you write:

```
@base <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
<> a owl:Ontology .
```

you mean:

```
<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

you would have to add a `#` explicitly to have it in the IRI:

```
@base <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
<#> a owl:Ontology .
```

means:

```
<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> a owl:Ontology .
```

If you want to add a non empty fragment identifier, you need the `#` as well:

```
@base <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
<#Entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

means:

```
<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#Entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

Second, if you use a non empty string between the `<` and `>`, and it is not a fragment identifier, then the IRI is constructed by getting rid of the local part of the base, which is whatever appear after the last `/` of the path of the IRI. E.g.,

```
@base <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
<Entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

means:

```
<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/Entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

Another example:

```
@base <http://my-url.com/something/?uri=http://example.com/anything> .
<Entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

means:

```
<http://my-url.com/something/Entity> a owl:Ontology .
```

This is not, properly speaking, a direct answer to your question(s) but should suffice to allow you to take the right decision.

Comment: If I replace
`@base <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .`
with
`@base <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity> .`
(removing the `#`), would your examples still work the same, or would the `entity` part then be missing in all the relative IRIs?

Comment: The hash in a `@base` declaration really doesn't make any difference, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [the answer by Antonine Zimmermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693652/586229),
I came up with this solution:

```
@base          <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity> .
@prefix ent:   <#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

<>
  a owl:Ontology .

ent:MyClass
  a owl:Class .
```

This way, I can use both `@base` and the named prefix `ent:` without having to repeat the base-IRI.

I chose named over empty prefix, because it makes the code more portable
and creates nicer output with `rdf2dot` (and probably other tools).